# How to recover y-coordinates when using XZ Montgomery curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-equations

I am using Montgomery ladder with Montgomery curve $by^2=x^3+ax^2+x$ using XZ coordinates and I recovered the $X$ value using $X3=X1/Z1$, but I don't know how to recover the $Y$ coordinates.

for Double and add ladder I am using this:

```
      A = X2+Z2
      AA = A2
      B = X2-Z2
      BB = B2
      E = AA-BB
      C = X3+Z3
      D = X3-Z3
      DA = D*A
      CB = C*B
      X5 = Z1*(DA+CB)2
      Z5 = X1*(DA-CB)2
      X4 = AA*BB
      Z4 = E*(BB+a24*E)
```

I tried this way :

```
x3=2;
y3 = mod(mod((x3.^3 + mod(a*x3.^2,p)+x3),p) * mod(modinvr(b,p),p),p);

for y = 0:22
    x = mod(y^2, 23);
    if x == y3
        fprintf("y = %d\n", y);// here I got two values of y 8 and 15
    end
end
```

here I got two values of y 8 and 15 both are correct points on the curve but in my case I want to choose `8` because the affine scalar point is `(2,8)` I have another point on the curve `(2,15)` but not in my scalar point! so that's why I need to select `8` instead of `15`.

values used: `a=6` `b=7` base point `(8,1)` and these the points on the curve:

```
     0     0
     2     8
     2    15
     3     9
     3    14
     7     0
     8     1
     8    22
     9     2
     9    21
    10     0
    11     7
    11    16
    12     2
    12    21
    17     3
    17    20
    18     4
    18    19
    19     2
    19    21
    21     5
    21    18
```

the resource is from this link: [Montgomery curve XZ coordinates](https://www.hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-montgom-xz.html)

Comment: Please introduce objects in their natural order, so first the curve, best in its homogeneous equation to avoid confusions of having an $(x,y)$-equation and using "$XZ$-coordinates". Is the $Y$-coordinate then normed to one? What are the used values for $a,b$? Which is the base field, which is the characteristic? Please insert human data, that can be checked with pen and paper, which points are known on which curve?

Comment: @dan_fulea thanks for your comments and I edited the question,